# Asynchronous http client without waiting for the whole queue

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

There is a task to process a number of long http requests (20-30 seconds). As soon as a reply is received or a timeout occurs, the request has to be executed again without waiting for the rest.

My code:

```py
enter code here

async def get(key):
    url = f "https://mysite?key={key}"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, timeout=20) as response:
            return await response.json()

coroutines = [get(key1), get(key1), get(key3)]

async def main():
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(coroutines):
        resp = await task
        print(f'resp: {resp}')
```

Can I somehow update the contents of the `asyncio.as_completed(coroutines)` generator when one of the tasks finishes without stopping the other tasks in it?

As a result, I would like to have an infinite loop that repeats each request as soon as it is completed.
The contents of the coroutines list are not constant. At any time new keys may appear or existing ones may become obsolete.
I may have chosen the wrong way to do this.

Comment: Mind telling us what you will do for each completed requests?

Comment: This is essentially a handler for a lot of Telegram bots working with getUpdates. Depending on what data I get in the request (if I get anything at all) I will send a response to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you probably chose wrong way - it's much easier to design it with *Consumer-Producer* pattern.

What you did at `resp = await task` can essentially be replaced by separate tasks listening for incoming data.

And producer will be multiple tasks that's listening to the individual URL, with `while` loop keeping each of task running non-stop.

To connect these 2 types of tasks, `Queue` is commonly used.

I strongly suggest reading [Official document](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines-and-tasks) about it, I know it's indeed a boring task! But will help you in the long-run.

---

client.py

```py
"""
Demo codes for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417266
"""


import asyncio
from typing import Dict

import aiohttp


async def process_response_queue(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    """
    Get json response data from queue.
    Effectively consumer.

    Args:
        queue: Queue for receiving url & json response pair
    """
    print("Processor started")

    while True:
        url_from, data = await queue.get()

        # do what you want here
        print(f"Received {data} from {url_from}")


class TaskManager:
    """
    Manage data fetching tasks
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.tasks: Dict[str, asyncio.Task] = {}

    async def get_repeat(self, url, timeout=20):
        """
        Repeatedly fetch json response from given url and put into queue.
        Effectively producer.

        Args:
            url: URL to fetch from
            timeout: Time until timeout
        """
        print(f"Task for {url} started")

        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                while True:
                    async with session.get(url, timeout=timeout) as resp:
                        await self.queue.put((url, await resp.json()))
        finally:
            del self.tasks[url]
            print(f"Task for {url} canceled")

    def start_processor(self):
        """
        Starts the processor.
        """
        self.tasks["_processor"] = asyncio.create_task(process_response_queue(self.queue))

    def start_new_task(self, url):
        """
        Create new task from url.

        Args:
            url: URL to fetch from.
        """
        self.tasks[url] = asyncio.create_task(self.get_repeat(url))

    def stop_task(self, url):
        """
        Stop existing task associated with url.

        Args:
            url: URL associated with task.

        Raises:
            KeyError: If no task associated with given url exists.
        """
        self.tasks[url].cancel()

    def close(self):
        """
        Cancels all tasks
        """

        for task in self.tasks.values():
            task.cancel()


async def main():
    """
    Starter code
    """

    task_manager = TaskManager()

    task_manager.start_processor()

    for n in range(5):
        task_manager.start_new_task(f"http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key={n}")

    # wait 10 sec
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    # cancel 1 task
    task_manager.stop_task("http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=3")

    # wait 20 sec
    await asyncio.sleep(20)

    # stop all
    task_manager.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

server.py

```py
"""
Demo codes for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417266
"""

import trio
from quart import request, jsonify
from quart_trio import QuartTrio


app = QuartTrio("Very named Much app")


@app.get("/json")
async def send_json():
    """
    Sleeps 5 + n seconds before returning response.

    Returns:
        json response
    """
    key = int(request.args["key"])

    await trio.sleep(5 + key)
    return jsonify({"key": key})


trio.run(app.run_task)
```

I just used trio for server part because I love [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) - take server part as mere example as you seems to have your own server.

---

Example output:

```
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0 started
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=1 started
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=2 started
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=3 started
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=4 started
Received {'key': 0} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0
Received {'key': 1} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=1
Received {'key': 2} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=2
Received {'key': 3} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=3
Received {'key': 4} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=4
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=3 canceled
Received {'key': 0} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0
Received {'key': 1} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=1
Received {'key': 2} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=2
Received {'key': 0} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0
Received {'key': 4} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=4
Received {'key': 1} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=1
Received {'key': 0} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0
Received {'key': 2} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=2
Received {'key': 1} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=1
Received {'key': 0} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0
Received {'key': 4} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=4
Received {'key': 2} from http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=2
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=0 canceled
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=1 canceled
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=2 canceled
Task for http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?key=4 canceled

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And if you didn't already, feel free to check out Stack Overflow [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)!